# Online, evolving, collaborative foundational text projects

Tags: soft-question, big-list

There are two *online, evolving, collaborative "foundational text" projects for research mathematicians* that I am aware of:

(1) [The Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu) for algebraic geometry

(2) [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/about) for categorical homotopy theory

They are sort of Bourbaki for the internet age. I'd like to know if there are others of the *same nature* that are ongoing or in the offing.

Please note that I am not looking for texts or monographs available online which is why I have highlighted the adjectives in the first line.

Comment: [Polymath](https://polymathprojects.org) seems pretty close.  By the way, since this is clearly a `{big-list}` question with no right answer, you probably want to make it Community Wiki, which you do by flagging it for moderator attention.

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, thanks! How do I flag it? Polymath as I understand it is not for writing foundational research-level texts collaboratively, but for doing research collaboratively.

Comment: Neither Kerodon nor the Stacks Project is collaborative.  Kerodon is written exclusively by Jacob Lurie.  The Stacks Project theoretically allows for external submissions, but Johan de Jong wrote 703685 out of 709534 lines in the Stacks Project, i.e., 99.18%.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: That is interesting and good to know! I was not aware of it. Their "About" sections suggest that they aim to be collaborative, but the reality may well be different.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov The line count in the repository is not an ideal system, because Johan plays two roles in the Stacks project: editor and (main) author, and either way he will be assigned his name to the line count. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06LB lists major contributions by others, often edited for consistency by Johan, but that doesn't take away that Johan has indeed written the great majority. There are many small contributions by others though. And we are looking into ways to get more external contributions.

Comment: @pbelmans: Your link leads to CRings, an open source collaborative project inspired by the Stacks project and meant to provide the commutative algebra background material. It doesn't seem to be active currently - last GitHub entry is from 7 years ago and some of the links don't work - but the final result (?) is downloadable as a PDF file from http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/cr.html and looks pretty substantial.

Comment: @pbelmans: Then why not supply your own statistics for the git repository, computed in a way that you deem appropriate, if you think that my statistics is substantially distorted?  I've looked at the tag 06LB, and the total amount of text presented there inside the cited links appears to be consistent with my previously cited estimate of external contributions comprising less than 1% of total material.

Comment: How about [Homotopy type theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/)? There is a book about foundational mathematics, written under a pseudonym, and various evolving libraries of formal mathematics.

Answer (score 30):

**Mathlib** is an online, evolving, collaborative project, aiming to be a foundation for all of modern pure mathematics. It is [fully searchable](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/), and [here is its homepage](https://leanprover-community.github.io/).
It is [hosted on github](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib), and it is all checked with the Lean Theorem Prover.

A great place to see the current state of mathlib is [this overview page](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib-overview.html), which the community keeps up to date.

There are still some parts of undergraduate mathematics not covered by mathlib, but on the other hand there is plenty of advanced mathematics there; for example recent (2020) achievements include a bunch of MSc level commutative algebra (e.g. [DVRs](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/ring_theory/discrete_valuation_ring.html)), a start on [homological algebra](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/homology/homology.html), [Lie algebras](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/classical_lie_algebras.html), a bunch of abstract measure theory and [Haar measure](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/measure_theory/haar_measure.html), [manifolds and bundles](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/geometry/manifold/basic_smooth_bundle.html). My list will go out of date quickly however -- check out the overview page for recent achievements.

Around 100 people have contributed so far, ranging from high school kids to full professors (in particular it *is* genuinely collaborative); all you have to do is to learn the Lean programming language so you can express mathematics in Lean, and then formalise something that we want in the library. We welcome contributions from many areas of mathematics -- as well as standard UG and MSc material in number theory, geometry, topology, analysis and algebra there is combinatorial game theory, Euclidean geometry and lots of other things. [Here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/undergrad_todo.html) is a list of undergraduate-level material which we still do not have.

Three years ago the library had essentially nothing (no complex numbers, no sine and cosine, for example). But it is [growing fast](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_stats.html) and my personal belief is that ultimately it is a more modern way of presenting mathematics than the Stacks Project and Kerodon. Within the next few years, all being well, part of mathlib will be integrating with the Stacks Project; both the mathlib people and the stacks project people are interested in the collaboration, and [this recent PR by Scott Morrison](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/pull/3937) (one of the founders of MathOverflow!) is another stepping stone towards schemes; we should have them in mathlib within the next few weeks (they already exist in Lean code but we have learnt the hard way that stuff not in mathlib is liable to bitrot). The reason I think mathlib will ultimately be more important that the Stacks Project or Kerodon is that mathlib is machine-readable, enabling computers to read research-level mathematics. Unfortunately computers still cannot understand natural language, meaning that it is difficult for AI to use e.g. ArXiv to do mathematics at research level, so right now it seems to me that formalisation is a natural way to proceed. I believe that it is inevitable that one day machines will be doing mathematics well, just like it was inevitable that one day they would play chess and go well; indeed one of the reasons I am motivated to work on mathlib is that I want machines to do arithmetic geometry well and this will only happen if professional arithmetic geometers like me explain arithmetic geometry to a computer.

People interested in contributing can take a look at the [Zulip chat](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/) -- this is a focussed chat room where people use their real names and experts work on questions which have arisen from the formalisation of mathematics. There are sometimes 1000 posts in a day and a lot of the conversation is highly technical, but there is a `#new members` stream where beginners can ask questions. Please read the [community guidelines](https://leanprover-community.github.io/meet.html). In short -- be nice. It's as simple as that.

Mathematicians wishing to learn something about how to contribute might find the [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlF-CfQhukNlxexiNJErGJd2dte_J1t1N) from last month's introductory workshop [Lean for the curious mathematician](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lftcm2020/) interesting. There is also the ongoing book [Mathematics in Lean](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathematics_in_lean/).

Answer (score 21):

I wouldn't say Kerodon is collaborative, but why the $n$Lab isn't in the list?

Personally, I would mention two books:

Kennington's "Differential geometry reconstructed" http://www.geometry.org/tex/conc/dgstats.php the author develops everything in great detail from the start, and by "the start" I mean his personal views on metamathematics, predicate logic, sequent calculus, algebra, analysis, and all the topology you'll ever see/need.

The last release of "Foundations of almost ring theory" https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409584 where the authors take personally the absence of a comprehensive textbook on 2-category theory.

Comment: Speaking of non-collaborative-ness, is either of your references collaborative?

Comment: Well, no, but apart the stacks project and the $n$Lab...

Comment: @Fosco: Thanks for the suggestions, but I am only looking for online projects that qualify on all the counts mentioned in the first line of my post, so online textbooks you mention don't come under its purview. There is no dearth of online texts which, of course, are also admirable, valuable and suited to our times.

Comment: @Fosco: $n$Lab in my view is not a systematic foundational text development enterprise. It seems to be more of an encyclopedia for certain areas of mathematics, although certainly online, evolving, collaborative and aimed at research mathematicians.

Comment: @user164113: Maybe you should clarify first what "evolving" and "collaborative" means.  arXiv texts certainly evolve when new versions are posted, and they are collaborative if they have 2 or more authors, more so than the Stacks Project and Kerodon.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: It is quite alright to use your own interpretation of the terms and suggest the projects you think are in the spirit of the question. I've tried to refine my criteria through my comments on why I think nLab, Polymath, and the two textbooks mentioned above don't satisfy one or the other of them. My model ultimately is Bourbaki as adapted to the internet and new ways and possibilities for collaboration it offers.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov, "[more so than the Stacks Project](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369863/online-evolving-collaborative-foundational-text-projects#comment934096_369868)"?  It's hard to imagine anything being more collaborative than Stacks, which adapts the open-source software model to mathematics texts, and certainly a 2-author arXiv text seems not to rise to that bar (however admirable it otherwise is).

Comment: @LSpice: I am not sure I am following you.  What does open source has to do with being collaborative?  If the software on which the project runs became proprietary, would the project cease being collaborative?  What exactly do you mean by an "open-source software model"?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov, "(open-source software) model" means just the model of open-source software (regardless of the actual software used); so an open-source textbook is one in which anyone can see the source (of the text) and, more importantly, can contribute.  For example, if I want to add something to the Stacks Project, I can do so easily, via git; but, if I want to add something to a 2-author paper, then both technology and social expectation are against me.  The fact that one author did the vast body of the work doesn't, I think, mean it's not collaborative; it just means it's got a leader.

Comment: @LSpice: Your claims about technology apply equally well to arXiv: all papers on arXiv come with their TeX source, which can be compiled as one pleases.  As for the “vast body of work”: if somebody writes a 243-page book, with a 2-page introduction (the numbers chosen to match the Stacks Project) by somebody else, should we consider this project “collaborative”?  The proportions are a bit too extreme for this, I would say.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov The total amount of collaboration that was involved in the Stacks project is quite high. For example, there are 406 credited contributors, and there have been multiple workshops devoted to writing new material for the Stacks project. It's true that the amount done by Johan alone is even greater than this. But the total amount of collaboration is higher than almost any paper on arXiv.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov The fact that I technically can download the source code of an arXiv paper and edit it is not so relevant, because if I then share this with another mathematician I will probably have completed some ethical breach like plagiarism or putting words in someone else's mouth. The only way to change the publicly accessible copy is to email the author. Of course if I email them that I found a mistake, they will probably fix it, but this is because of a failure (a mistake).

Comment: On the other hand, if I make contributions to the stacks project and they are included, this is the system working as intended. The intent is significant here, and the technical implementation flows from that intent.

Comment: @WillSawin: Your comment about “406 credited contributors” is correct and highly misleading: the overwhelming majority of these contributors noticed a typo or two.  Johan de Jong mentions explicitly somewhere that he includes everybody in this list, no matter how small the contribution.  By your standard, many arXiv papers would have dozens of collaborators instead of the current 2 or 3, simply because dozens of people noticed typos.  Once you rescale to the size of a typical arXiv paper, the total amount of collaboration is much less than almost any paper on arXiv with 2 or more authors.

Comment: Concerning your observations about the ability of others to add new material, they are correct, but that's not what “collaborative” means.  Not every collaborative work is a publicly editable wiki.  And I bet that Johan de Jong serves as the final arbiter of what does and does not get into the Stacks Project.

Comment: @Fosco The nLab is not an encyclopedia. It is a wiki-lab, i.e. a modern version of a lab book, specifically for mathematics and related topics with a focus on category theory.

Answer (score 13):

An extremely exciting project belonging to this list is [Yiannis Sakellaridis](http://math.jhu.edu/%7Esakellar/)'s [Automorphic Project](https://automorphic.jh.edu/)!

Comment: Would you please provide an explicit link to a PDF or to where the book can be read online?

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy From what I understand, Sakellaridis is working on setting up a website for the book ([http://math.jhu.edu/automorphic/](http://math.jhu.edu/automorphic/)), but (for now) it only works when accessed from the JHU intranet. I think currently the only way to get a PDF is to clone the repo and compile it from the source...

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy, the [website](https://automorphic.jh.edu/) seems to be up now! [PDF](http://math.jhu.edu/~sakellar/automorphic-files/book.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

For number theory, there is this very interesting project similar to the Stacks project that seems to cover in great detail all of the main subfields of modern number theory:

https://github.com/holdenlee/number-theory